# How to use random to combine different phrases python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use random to generate a random username with a random amount of names from a tuple containing random names. I tried some code, but I was not successful.

This is code I have tried but it gave me this: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8728c52580>` when I printed it

```
randnames = ['ender', 'Pro', 'itz', 'YT', 'Chill', 'Mom', 'Playz', 'Games', 'fortnite', 'prokid', 'monkey', 'Gamer', 'GirlGamer', 's1mp', 'lowping', 'ihave', 'getgud', 'istupid', '123', 'minecraft', 'LMAO', 'non']
username = f'{random.choice(randnames) for i in range(random.randint(1, 8))}'
```

Comment: It looks like you want a string in the end, but what what specifically is the result you are trying to get? Just a big long string like `'123itzPlayzMommonkeyenderPlayz'`? Is so: `''.join(random.choice(randnames) for i in range(random.randint(1, 8)))` might be what you want.

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what is your excepted output ?

Comment: @Mark thank you, it did work and that's what i was looking for, and sorry if I was unclear (I'm new to stackoverflow)

Comment: @WindowsIsCool fwiw, `choices()` might be better here: `''.join(random.choices(randnames, k=random.randint(1, 8)))` the `k` parameter tells how many choices to take.

Comment: ok, thank you! I will use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the line

```
random.choice(randnames) for i in range(random.randint(1, 8))
```

which returns a generator object instead of a string, so when you try to convert it to a string using an `fstring` you just print the object.

if you convert it to a list using list you can see the output change to a list of  random names

```
f"{list(random.choice(randnames) for i in range(random.randint(1, 8)))}"
```

OUTPUT:

```
['prokid', 'Chill', 'non', 'Playz']
```

But to get the output you desire, you should use `''.join` which takes an iterable (like the generator object you made using comprehension) and concatenates all the elements of it together.

```
randnames = ['ender', 'Pro', 'itz', 'YT', 'Chill', 'Mom', 'Playz', 'Games', 'fortnite', 'prokid', 'monkey', 'Gamer', 'GirlGamer', 's1mp', 'lowping', 'ihave', 'getgud', 'istupid', '123', 'minecraft', 'LMAO', 'non']
username = ''.join(random.choice(randnames) for i in range(random.randint(1, 8)))
```

if you do `print(username)` and if the same random names were selected you would instead get

```
prokidChillnonPlayz
```

Which is what you wanted.